# python shows me only one character instead what I expect why?

Tags: python, output

I built up a program. program is running well and also not any error but It's return only one character. I want all characters?

***Explain about code:***

There is string (s). so what I did here,
 I just reverse lowercase() to uppercase() hole string:

( `HackerRank.com presents "Pythoinst 2"`) ***converted into*** (`hACKERrANK.com pRESENTS "pYTHON 2"`).

***I've already tried:***

```
def swap_case(s):
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].isupper():
      print('%s'%s[i].lower(), end='')   # look at this line code
    else:
      print('%s'%s[i].upper(), end='')   # look at this line code
if __name__ == '__main__':
  s = 'HackerRank.com presents \"Pythoinst 2\".'
  result = swap_case(s)
  print(result)
```

***Output:***

```
hACKERrANK.COM PRESENTS "pYTHOINST 2".None  <---- I don't want this None.
```

***Problem:***

```
....NST 2".None <--- I don't this "None" string. Every time this is print automatic.
```

***This is my code:***

```
def swap_case(s):
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].isupper():
      return'{}'.format(s[i].lower(), end='')
    else:
      return '{}'.format(s[i].upper(), end='')
if __name__ == '__main__':
  s = 'HackerRank.com presents \"Pythoinst 2\".'
  result = swap_case(s)
  print(result)
```

***I'm getting this Output:***

```
h
```

***I expected this output:***

```
hACKERrANK.COM PRESENTS "pYTHOINST 2".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function prints everything you need, so don't save and print the result. Change

```
result = swap_case(s)
print(result)
```

to just

```
swap_case(s)
```

Full code (unnecessary string formatting removed):

```
def swap_case(s):
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].isupper():
      print(s[i].lower(), end='')
    else:
      print(s[i].upper(), end='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  s = 'HackerRank.com presents \"Pythoinst 2\".'
  swap_case(s)
```

---

EDIT:

Turns out you can't modify the stuff under `if __name__ == '__main__':`. So, change your function to this:

```
def swap_case(s):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i].isupper():
      result.append(s[i].lower())
    else:
      result.append(s[i].upper())
  return ''.join(result)
```

Here is a more Pythonic version:

```
def swap_case(s):
  return ''.join([c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper() for c in s])
```

Comment: visit this link.This is a coding challenge: [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/swap-case/problem?isFullScreen=true)

Comment: I can't change  '__name__=='__main___'  function.

Comment: can you make this right comprehension :  return [string[i:i+3] if string[i:i+3]==sub_string] for i in range(len(string))], def count(string, sub_string)

Comment: @Rohit Sounds like you have a separate question. Why not open a new one?